# Can I make scripts temporarily "not exist" with CSS?

Tags: html, css

For instance,

```
<div style='display:none;'>
    <!-- JavaScript scripts and php function that otherwise would run automatically -->
</div>
```

. Say for example that I'd like a script not to run whilst on a mobile unit or so. Is this possible with CSS?

Comment: Do you mean you want CSS that only applies to mobile, or you want your css to remove a script tag when on mobile? If it's the latter, you can't do it with CSS, but you can with JS or your server side script (In your case, PHP)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a JS code that should not be available for mobile users you can do like

```
if (!(typeof window.orientation !== 'undefined')) {
 //Code that is not available for mobile users 
}
```